# Error while deploying a game to an iPad. 'Can't install application'

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error while deploying to an iPad using Xcode. I am able to deploy it using iTunes but it does not work with Xcode. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The provisioning that you're using is Developer or Distribution? 
For both you must have to associate the iPad at provisioning, Distribution does not allow to debug applications.

Comment: yeah that seems about right. I will check on that. Thanks